# Crear models.forms dinamicamente en Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Buenas Noches con todos

Existe alguna manera para crear formulario Django a partir de los modelos Django existentes de forma dinamica, automatica o talvez realizando un for o blucle.

Hago esta pregunta ya si tengo por ejemplo 2 modelos Company y Book, entonces tendría que crear los formularios en el archivo forms.py realizando lo siguiente:

```
class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Company

class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Book
```

Como se pueden dar cuenta es algo repetitivo y si en ves de 2 modelos tengo 100 modelos , eso sería un trabajo muy repetitivo.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varios temas aqui, primero, con respecto a tu duda puntual, te enseñare una manera,no sin antes aclarar que no es recomendable...conoces django contentype ? [Documentación django contenttype](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), pues bien, es alli donde se almacena la data de los modelos django, asi que una de las posibles soluciones seria esta:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType  
from django import forms  

def get_object_form( id_tipo,  excludes=None ):  
    tipo = ContentType.objects.get( pk=id_tipo ) 
    modelo = tipo.model_class( ) 
    class _ObjectForm( forms.ModelForm ):
        class Meta:
            model = modelo
            fields = '__all__'
    return _ObjectForm
```

Basicamente, se hace un queryset a contentype con la pk del modelo en cuestión. No es viable por supuesto, para iterar todo los modelos y crear un form para cada uno sino mas como una función reutilizable que permita recibir cualquiera, en las vistas solo es que la llames asignada a una variable y luego puedes utilizar todos los metodos normales de django forms como save().

Ahora, por que no es recomendable:
Como sabes, la idea de los forms para cada modelo es que puedas jugar con los campos creando ciertas reglas de validación o modificando su estructura como consideres, no todos los modelos tienen los mismos campos o los mismos patrones de datos....si el argumento es que pueden haber 100 modelos en tu aplicación, creo que ya el tema es revisar el diseño del modelo de datos en si,pues a lo mejor no esta correcto, es demasiado pesado y posiblemente requiera modularidad.

Espero te haya servido y haya sido claro.

Comment: Asumiendo que es la última versión de Django (2.0), entonces es necesario definir los `fields` en la clase `Meta`.

Comment: @César Correcto, actualizé la respuesta.

Comment: Jsanchez la verdad desconocía lo que me mencionas , pero me parece genial la solución que me diste , por otro lado tienes mucha razón en que no todos los formularios tendrían las mismas validaciones , quería ahorrarme tiempo en no estar creando los formularios pero me parece algo necesario dependiendo de lo que necesite, muchas gracias por tu aporte , de igual forma me ayuda en otros temas

Comment: Es con todo gusto